# Effective way to convert/create matrix from mixed cell/string

Tags: matlab

Sometimes there might be more that one string located somewhere else, so I need a way to find everyone in the cell array. I have a cell array like the one below and I need a fast and effective way to 1) remove the empty columns, 2) convert the cells containing a string with "#" to the number after the "#" (6.504), and finally 3) create or convert the whole cell array to a data matrix like "data" below. Is there a smart way to do all this? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
array ={ 
    [47.4500]    ''    [23.9530]    ''    [12.4590]
    [34.1540]    ''    [15.1730]    ''    [ 9.6840]
    [45.2510]    ''    [23.3770]    ''    [13.0670]
    [29.9350]    ''    [14.8680]    ''    '# 6.504'}

data =[
        47.4500   23.9530   12.4590
        34.1540   15.1730    9.6840
        45.2510   23.3770   13.0670
        29.9350   14.8680    6.5040]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns with mixed types are tricky to handle, but if the format always follows the regex pattern `# \d+(?:\.\d+)` you can proceed as follows:

```
C = { 
  47.4500   ''    23.9530   ''    12.4590
  34.1540   ''    15.1730   ''     9.6840
  45.2510   ''    23.3770   ''    13.0670
  29.9350   ''    14.8680   ''   '# 6.504'
};

% Get rid of empty columns...
C(:,all(cellfun(@ischar,C))) = [];

% Convert numeric strings into numeric values...
C = cellfun(@(x)convert(x),C,'UniformOutput',false);

% Convert the cell matrix into a numeric matrix...
C = cell2mat(C);
```

Where the `convert` function is defined as follows:

```
function x = convert(x)
    if (~ischar(x))
        return;
    end

    x = str2double(strrep(x,'# ',''));
end
```

Comment: Hi Tommaso, Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I do however get the following error message: **Error: File: script.m Line: 18 Column: 1
Function definitions are not permitted in this context.**

Comment: Did you place that function somewhere? Maybe at the bottom of your current script or into another file within the current working folder?

Comment: You are right, i forgot the function, When I placed in in the bottom of my script I get this message: **Error: File: script.m Line: 18 Column: 1
Function definitions are not permitted in this context.**

Comment: Probably some missing closure in previous functions or things like that. Place it into a separate file for the moment.

Comment: sorry for asking, but if a create a new function file called Func, how do I call it from the script?

Comment: For example, you create a new script called `convert.m` in the current working directory. You paste the `convert` function inside it and you have it. Now you can call it from other scripts without problems, with just its name.

Comment: That is AWESOME. Thanks a lot. Do you know if i can use the same procedure in a GUI code?

Comment: Perfect. I will give it a try. Thanks a lot